# AngularJS: $q wait for all even when 1 rejected

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to wait for a couple of promises with Angular's $q but there seems to be no option to 'wait for all even when a promis is rejected'.
I've created an example (http://jsfiddle.net/Zenuka/pHEf9/21/) and I want a function to be executed when all promises are resolved/rejected, is that possible?
Something like:

```
$q.whenAllComplete(promises, function() {....})
```

EDIT: In the example you see that the second service fails and immediately after that the function in `$q.all().then(..., function(){...})` is being executed. I want to wait for the fifth promise to be completed.

Comment: will you use $http to get request ?

Comment: For some of the promises...

Comment: use $q.all('array of promise')

Comment: See the JSFiddle and question, because $q.all(..).then runs immediately after a promise is rejected but I want to wait for all even when one is rejected.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Ok, I've implemeted a basic version myself (I only want to wait for an array of promises). Anyone can extend this or create a cleaner version if they want to :-)
Check the jsfiddle to see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Zenuka/pHEf9/

```
angular.module('test').config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        var $q = $delegate;

        // Extention for q
        $q.allSettled = $q.allSettled || function (promises) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (angular.isArray(promises)) {
                var states = [];
                var results = [];
                var didAPromiseFail = false;
                if (promises.length === 0) { 
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }

                // First create an array for all promises with their state
                angular.forEach(promises, function (promise, key) {
                    states[key] = false;
                });

                // Helper to check if all states are finished
                var checkStates = function (states, results, deferred, failed) {
                    var allFinished = true;
                    angular.forEach(states, function (state, key) {
                        if (!state) {
                            allFinished = false;
                        }
                    });
                    if (allFinished) {
                        if (failed) {
                            deferred.reject(results);
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(results);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Loop through the promises
                // a second loop to be sure that checkStates is called when all states are set to false first
                angular.forEach(promises, function (promise, key) {
                    $q.when(promise).then(function (result) {
                        states[key] = true;
                        results[key] = result;
                        checkStates(states, results, deferred, didAPromiseFail);
                    }, function (reason) {
                        states[key] = true;
                        results[key] = reason;
                        didAPromiseFail = true;
                        checkStates(states, results, deferred, didAPromiseFail);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                throw 'allSettled can only handle an array of promises (for now)';
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        return $q;
    }]);
}]);
```

Comment: I was able to throw this into my application really easily. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: At least angular 1.2.16 can handle arrays and objects with keynames with forEach, so you can remove the isArray check and use the functionality for both.

Comment: I was able to use this, thank you.  However this does not gracefully handle the case where you pass an empty array (no promises).  To handle this, I've added the following right below the "var didAPromiseFail = false;" line:

if (promises.length === 0) {
    deferred.resolve(results);
}

Answer (score 20):

Analogous to how `all()` returns an array/hash of the resolved values, the [`allSettled()` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) from Kris Kowal's Q returns a collection of objects that look either like:

```
{ state: 'fulfilled', value: <resolved value> }
```

or:

```
{ state: 'rejected', reason: <rejection error> }
```

As this behavior is rather handy, I've ported the function to Angular.js's $q:

```
angular.module('your-module').config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        var $q = $delegate;

        $q.allSettled = $q.allSettled || function allSettled(promises) {
            // Implementation of allSettled function from Kris Kowal's Q:
            // https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled

            var wrapped = angular.isArray(promises) ? [] : {};

            angular.forEach(promises, function(promise, key) {
                if (!wrapped.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    wrapped[key] = wrap(promise);
                }
            });

            return $q.all(wrapped);

            function wrap(promise) {
                return $q.when(promise)
                    .then(function (value) {
                        return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
                    }, function (reason) {
                        return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
                    });
            }
        };

        return $q;
    }]);
}]);
```

Credit goes to:

- Zenuka for [the decorator code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18891109/27581)
- Benjamin Gruenbaum for [pointing me in the right direction](https://gist.github.com/JGarrido/8100714#comment-1293045)
- [The `all` implementation](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L515) from Angular.js source

Comment: Just added this to our app. Works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The promise API in angularJS is based on https://github.com/kriskowal/q. I looked at API that `Q` provides and it had a method `allSettled`, but this method has not been exposed over the port that AngularJS uses. This is form the documentation

> The all function returns a promise for an array of values. When this
>   promise is fulfilled, the array contains the fulfillment values of the
>   original promises, in the same order as those promises. If one of the
>   given promises is rejected, the returned promise is immediately
>   rejected, not waiting for the rest of the batch. If you want to wait
>   for all of the promises to either be fulfilled or rejected, you can
>   use allSettled.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this same issue recently. This was the problem:

- I had an array of promises to handle, `promises`
- I wanted to get all the results, resolve or reject
- I wanted the promises to run in parallel

This was how I solved the problem:

```
promises = promises.map(
    promise => promise.catch(() => null)
);
$q.all(promises, results => {
    // code to handle results
});
```

It's not a general fix, but it is simple and and easy to follow. Of course if any of your promises could resolve to null then you can't distinguish between that a rejection, but it works in many cases and you can always modify the catch function to work with the particular problem you're solving.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the inspiration Zenuka, you can find my version at https://gist.github.com/JGarrido/8100714

Here it is, in it's current state:

```
.config( function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator("$q", ["$delegate", function($delegate) {
    var $q = $delegate;

    $q.allComplete = function(promises) {

      if(!angular.isArray(promises)) {
        throw Error("$q.allComplete only accepts an array.");
      }

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var passed = 0;
      var failed = 0;
      var responses = [];

      angular.forEach(promises, function(promise, index) {
        promise
          .then( function(result) {
            console.info('done', result);
            passed++;
            responses.push(result);
          })
          .catch( function(result) {
            console.error('err', result);
            failed++;
            responses.push(result);
          })
          .finally( function() {
            if((passed + failed) == promises.length) {
              console.log("COMPLETE: " + "passed = " + passed + ", failed = " + failed);

              if(failed > 0) {
                deferred.reject(responses);
              } else {
                deferred.resolve(responses);
              }
            }
          })
        ;
      });

      return deferred.promise;

    };

    return $q;
  }]);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach to solving this problem.

```
$provide.decorator('$q', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
    var $q = $delegate;

    $q.allSettled = $q.allSettled || function (promises) {
        var toSettle = [];

        if (angular.isArray(promises)) {
            angular.forEach(promises, function (promise, key) {
                var dfd = $q.defer();
                promise.then(dfd.resolve, dfd.resolve);
                toSettle.push(dfd.promise);
            });
        }

        return $q.all(toSettle);
    };

    return $q;
}]);
```

Comment: It's not the same thing. $q.all() do a parallel approach.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use catch() to handle any errors and stop rejections from propagating. You could do this by either not returning a value from catch() or by resolving using the error response and then handling errors in all(). This way $q.all() will always be executed.  I've updated the fiddle with a very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/pHEf9/125/

```
...
function handleError(response) {
    console.log('Handle error');
}

// Create 5 promises
var promises = [];
var names = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    var willSucceed = true;
    if (i == 2) willSucceed = false;
    promises.push(
      createPromise('Promise' + i, i, willSucceed).catch(handleError));
}
...
```

Be aware that if you don't return a value from within catch(), the array of resolved promises passed to all() will contain undefined for those errored elements.

Answer (score -3):

just use *finally*

```
$q.all(tasks).finally(function() {
                            // do stuff
                        });
```

Comment: -1: `$q.all()` rejects as soon as any of the promises is rejected, so `finally()` will get called immediately after `catch()` and it will not wait on all the promises to be fulfilled. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dimmreaper/3qj9ybLp/) for a demonstration (check the console to watch the timing of things happening.)